# How to render simple React component in MVC6 application, for dummies

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, asp.net5

I have a simple mvc6 site solution in Visual Studio 2015.

In one of my pages, I have

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('react-app-mount'));
</script>
```

But the component does not render. What scripts do I have to include in the page to make it render?
I am a total newbie to react.

Trying to figure it out on my own I got extremely confused with the gazillion of terms like '`npm`, `bower`, `babel`' but nowhere I can find a decent from-scratch example on how to use those things in Visual Studio 2015. Moreover, I find suggestions that just don't work.

For instance, I read something like "you should run `npm install babel`", but nobody gives information on where in visual studio I should execute this command. Others speak about a `package.json` file that is supposed to exist somewhere in my solution, but it is just not there.

I really don't understand why things are so extremely complicated. In the old days, when you wanted to use a library, you just put a `<script>` element on the beginning or end of your page and you could just use it.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts that you have to import are:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

But this is not the right way to do, It is for getting a demo of React.

If you want to get started with react, This might help you.
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: The example does not cover MVC6. I am using Visual Studio 2015. I need to render the main body of my page as a react component. My project has razor views, controllers etc. It is not a node.js project.

Answer (score 0):

the right way, using ASP.NET MVC is:

1. bundle all react components & scipts using webpack to one file: bundle.js

   1.2. you need entry point for your scripts, first script that will ReactDOM.render your root component, and alsi it will import this component:
   `import { App} from "./Components/App";`

   1.3. Your `App` component will import other components and so on
2. include bundle.js in your view layout
3. don't forget to include root node in your view file ("

Comment: Is this about a Single Page Application? I son't build an SPA. Also, is this using react in a modular way?

Comment: I really don't know how to use webpack in my mvc project and tutorials are not very specific. It seems I go deep down a rabbit hole every time I try to achieve something. I already spend two days trying to make it work. Time is so valuable, and I don't understand why is it so hard for end-developers to just use a library.